# Initialize global variable and display in MIPS

Tags: assembly, mips

I try to initial global variable in MIPS. After doing some alteration, I try to display the variable. But it seems to be not working. Can someone help me? Below is the code.

```
.data
globalVariable:  .word  10

.text
lw $a0, globalVariable 

la $a0, globalVariable #get address
li $a1, 11 #new value
sw $a1 0($a0) #save new value

lw $a2, globalVariable  #get new value
li   $v0, 1           # specify Print Integer service   
syscall  
   
li $v0, 10      #Systemcall code exit
syscall
```

Here is the output: 268500992

I am using MARS MIPS tool.

Comment: BTW, there's no point to the first `lw $a0, globalVariable` if you're just going to overwrite `$a0` in the next instruction.  And you're printing the address because `v0=1 / syscall` takes its arg in `$a0`.

Comment: syscall 1 uses `$a0` as the integer argument to print